# What is the simplest way to get the user's longitude and latitude in Android ? Even without using listener?

Tags: android, emulation, latitude-longitude, android-virtual-device

My app just need to know user's country, and my app doesn't care where user moves.

All I want to know is :
When user start app, app will send user's approximately location(latitude and longitude) to server.

Here is my code with error. I try to send a string to getlocation function, and I hope it can return original string with adding latitude and longitude information.

```
private String getlocation (String url){
    LocationManager status = (LocationManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));
    if (status.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || status.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.v("print","enable to locate");
    } else {
        Log.v("print","fail to locate");
    }
    Location location = status.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);  
    if(location!=null){ 
      Log.v("print","succed!!!@@");
      Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
      String loc=Double.toString(longitude);
      url=url+loc;
    }
    else{
        Log.v("print","location return null");
     }
    return url;
}
```

I use network_provider, and it always print "enable to locate", then print "location return null"

So what's wrong with my code that my location always return null.
I use AVD manerger, and I also try GPS_PROVIDER. I use Emulator control to send Decimal on location control. It doesn't work ,too.

By the way, I set network and GPS permission,too.

So much thanks for help!

Comment: did u check the logcat if it is asking for permissions to be added in the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting location by below code but enable " use wireless networks " in settings i.e ( through settings - Location services - use wireless networks)

```
public void getCurrentLocation() {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String bestProvider;

    // Get the location manager
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            Log.e(TAG, "Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+" , Longitude: "+location.getLongitude());
}
```

Comment: sorry~ Do you mean set Location services - use wireless networks on my AVD phone? I choose GPS and Wi-Fi & mobile network, but it doesn't work.
By the way, does locationManager need to be written in Asynctask?
Or just writting in MainActivity is fine?

Comment: I used you're code, and my app "unfortunately shut down" when location.getLatitude().

Comment: it is working on my tablet 101. galaxy.

use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>